# Android GeoCoder returns two different places for one adress

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the GeoCoder for getting lat and long coordinates by giving him street adress, post code, and country. I have only adresses for Germany.
There is a street called "Sandgrubenstraße" with its post code but he is adding a marker somewhere in Austria. But it should be added in Germany.

I found out, that there is the same street in Autria called "Sandgrubenstraße" but how does that work when I use the post code which is unique?

How can I prevent GeoCoder to add markers that are NOT in Germany? How can I restrict this behaviour ? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postcodes are not globally unique, different countries can and do have overlapping post codes and different standards. Adding the country name to geocode prevents this happening, so you should add "country" when filtering for address components.

`components=country:DE` should solve this.

Comment: Thank you. Where to add `components=country:DE` ?

Comment: I cannot guide you directly without knowing how you initialize and get your data, but in general you just put the component into your URL query you use to get your JSON/XML response from the api. Like "url.to.get.your.data... &sensor=false&components=country:DE"